# Why does document.evaluate return XPath results as nested items?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to query some xml using XPath.  Here is the xml (modified for privacy):

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-11d1-65B3-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
    <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
        <s:AttributeType name="SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID" rs:number="1" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="number" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="COLUMN_ID" rs:number="2" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="number" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="DSPLY_NM" rs:number="3" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="02" COLUMN_ID="1"   DSPLY_NM="One" />
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="03" COLUMN_ID="37"  DSPLY_NM="Two"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="04" COLUMN_ID="38"  DSPLY_NM="Three"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="05" COLUMN_ID="39"  DSPLY_NM="Four"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="06" COLUMN_ID="23"  DSPLY_NM="Five"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="07" COLUMN_ID="24"  DSPLY_NM="Six"/>
</rs:data>
<errors count="0"/>
</xml>
```

Here is a shim I pieced together to remediate some ancient IE code:

```
if (typeof MyNamespace.selectNodes === 'undefined') {
    MyNamespace.selectNodes = function(context, xp, namespace)  {
        if(!context)
        {
            throw new Error("selectNodes cannot have a null context");
        }

        var doc = (context.nodeType != 9 ? context.ownerDocument : context);

        if (typeof doc.evaluate !== 'undefined') {
            var nsresolver = null;
            if (namespace instanceof Object) {
                nsresolver = function(prefix) {
                    return namespace[prefix];
                };
            }

            const snapshot = doc.evaluate(xp, context, nsresolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
            return [...Array(snapshot.snapshotLength)].map((_, i) => snapshot.snapshotItem(i));
        } 

        throw new Error("no XPath engine found");
    };
}
```

Now when I run the following:

```
    this.xmlDOM = (new DomParser()).parseFromString(myXmlAsString);
    var result = MyNamespace.selectNodes(this.xmlDOM, '//rs:data/z:row', {
                                                                            s:   "uuid:BDC6E3F0-11d1-65B3-A2A3-00AA00C14882",
                                                                            dt:  "uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882",
                                                                            rs:  "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset",
                                                                            z:   "#RowsetSchema",
                                                                            xsl: "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                                                         });
```

I am expecting the result to contain 6 node elements (snapshotItems):

```
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="02" COLUMN_ID="1"   DSPLY_NM="One" />
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="03" COLUMN_ID="37"  DSPLY_NM="Two"/>
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="04" COLUMN_ID="38"  DSPLY_NM="Three"/>
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="05" COLUMN_ID="39"  DSPLY_NM="Four"/>
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="06" COLUMN_ID="23"  DSPLY_NM="Five"/>
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="07" COLUMN_ID="24"  DSPLY_NM="Six"/>
```

But what I get is ONE node element (snapshotItem) that looks like this:

```
<z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="02" COLUMN_ID="1"   DSPLY_NM="One" >
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="03" COLUMN_ID="37"  DSPLY_NM="Two">
        <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="04" COLUMN_ID="38"  DSPLY_NM="Three">
            <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="05" COLUMN_ID="39"  DSPLY_NM="Four">
                <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="06" COLUMN_ID="23"  DSPLY_NM="Five">
                    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="07" COLUMN_ID="24"  DSPLY_NM="Six">
                    </z:row>
                </z:row>
            </z:row>
        </z:row>
    </z:row>
</z:row>
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can achieve my expected result?

## Real Reason this wasn't working

So after the @martin-honnen posted his answer, that got me thinking about the source of my xml.

Turns out that the incoming xml had encoding issues (they had encoded text values using an HTML encoder instead of an xml encoder, so there were &nbsp; values sprinkled in the xml data.

This caused an error in the DOMParser when trying to parse this data using 'text/xml' as the data type.  So I decided to use the 'text/html' parser, export the text from that (which automatically converts all the &nbsp; and other such characters) and ingest the result into the parseString again but this time with 'text/xml' as the data type.

What I didn't realize is that the text/html parser does not support self-closing tags (for reasons which remain incomprehensible to me since <br/> has been in HTML for decades) and what it did to my data was convert:

```
<row>
    <data />
    <data />
    <data />
</row>
```

Into:

```
<row>
    <data>
    <data>
    <data></data></data></data>
</row>
```

From this newly-mangled version of xml, it should be evident why my xpath results were not what I expected.

Thanks to @martin-honnen for trying the one thing I didn't bother to try (I honestly didn't think the result would be different between my xml and my sample-xml, I didn't see the mangled closing tags) and this ultimately put me on the path to success.

Comment: what is `DomParser` - perhaps it fails to parse "empty" elements correctly - i.e. `<z:row .../>`

Comment: Or is it something about `MyNamespace.selectNodes` ... does that exist in some  browsers so your `shim` is not used? Because, if the XML is correctly parsed, then the code in the "shim" returns the expected result ... so the issue is either that `DomParser` is broken (probably doesn't understand empty elements), or `MyNamespace.selectNodes` is a function, and it is broken

Comment: DOMParser is the built in javascript DOMParser.

Comment: Built-in to what? in a browser it's `DOMParser` and its `parseFromString` method must be given 2 arguments - what is "DomParser" built in to?  also, DOMParser isn't "built in to javascript" - try running that in node - it won't

Answer (score 2):

Let's try your code (slightly adapted to make sense as a standalone snippet):

```js
const xml = `<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-11d1-65B3-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
    <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
        <s:AttributeType name="SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID" rs:number="1" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="number" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="COLUMN_ID" rs:number="2" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="number" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="DSPLY_NM" rs:number="3" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxlength="-1" rs:maybenull="True"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
    </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="02" COLUMN_ID="1"   DSPLY_NM="One" />
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="03" COLUMN_ID="37"  DSPLY_NM="Two"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="04" COLUMN_ID="38"  DSPLY_NM="Three"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="05" COLUMN_ID="39"  DSPLY_NM="Four"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="06" COLUMN_ID="23"  DSPLY_NM="Five"/>
    <z:row SEARCH_TYPE_COLUMN_ID="07" COLUMN_ID="24"  DSPLY_NM="Six"/>
</rs:data>
<errors count="0"/>
</xml>`;

const MyNamespace = {};

if (typeof MyNamespace.selectNodes === 'undefined') {
    MyNamespace.selectNodes = function(context, xp, namespace)  {
        if(!context)
        {
            throw new Error("selectNodes cannot have a null context");
        }

        var doc = (context.nodeType != 9 ? context.ownerDocument : context);

        if (typeof doc.evaluate !== 'undefined') {
            var nsresolver = null;
            if (namespace instanceof Object) {
                nsresolver = function(prefix) {
                    return namespace[prefix];
                };
            }

            const snapshot = doc.evaluate(xp, context, nsresolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
            return [...Array(snapshot.snapshotLength)].map((_, i) => snapshot.snapshotItem(i));
        } 

        throw new Error("no XPath engine found");
    };
}

const xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

var result = MyNamespace.selectNodes(xmlDoc, '//rs:data/z:row', {
                                                                            s:   "uuid:BDC6E3F0-11d1-65B3-A2A3-00AA00C14882",
                                                                            dt:  "uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882",
                                                                            rs:  "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset",
                                                                            z:   "#RowsetSchema",
                                                                            xsl: "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                                                         });
                                                                         
console.log(result.length, result);
```

Both Chrome and Firefox return an array with 6 `z:row` element nodes in the console.

Thus, as others have commented, either your `DomParser` is not relying on the browser's DOMParser and normal XML parsing or some other part of your code (serialization?) you haven't shown fails.

Comment: Very strange.  When I run your sample.  I get your results.  When I run my code which is essentially identical to yours (the only difference I can see is my xml has more attributes than what I provided here) then it doesn't work the same.  So it looks like there is something going on with more attributes or something about how the attributes were serialized.  Looks like I have hours of removing one thing at a time to try and find the problem.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: `which is essentially identical` ... lets break that down ... you use `DomParser` this code uses `DOMParser` ... you call `.parseFromString` with just one argument, this code sends the **required** second argument ... so it's not "essentially" anything but completely different at the core

Comment: Given your tone, not gonna bother arguing with you.  You clearly just want to broadcast how smart you are to the world.